# How to link something from manifest.json

Tags: php, html, json, webpack

I'm using Webpack with the CleanWebpackPlugin, but I use an index.php. So HtmlWebpackPlugin isn't an option. I found a different plugin called WebpackManifestPlugin. This creates a file with the files and their hash called manifest.json. It looks like this:

`{
  "main.js": "css.d915ef.js",
  "main.css": "main.d915ef.css"
}`

But how do I use this in my head?

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/main.css">`

Because this doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Use that function in php script

```
function asset($asset_name)
{
    $manifest = file_get_contents("./manifest.json");
    $manifest = json_decode($manifest, true); //decode json string to php associative array
    if (!isset($manifest[$asset_name])) return $asset_name; //if manifest.json doesn't contain $asset_name then return $asset_name itself
    return "/dist/" . $manifest[$asset_name];
}
```

It will read and parse `manifest.json` and replace `"main.js"` with `"css.d915ef.js"`
You can use `asset()` function while generating yout html, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo asset("main.js"); ?>">
```

Please, be aware, that `file_get_contents("./manifest.json")` will only work correctly if your php script and `manifest.json` is in the same folder. If not - you need to provide correct path to `manifest.json` here.

Comment: How can i use this script to generate link tags for css files and script tags for .js files?

Comment: @GyörgyKomáromi answer already contain example for css files

Comment: @Komi in solving a similar issue I have split the array in two parts: one with the files with the `.css` extension and another with the `.js` extension. I am then looping the two arrays in separate parts of the html and printing `<link>` tags for `.css` and `<script>` tags for `.js`

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation with Create React App and a PHP file.

The Create React App configuration creates an `asset-manifest.json` file in which all the files that are needed in the page are listed under the `entrypoints` key.

```
"entrypoints": [
  "static/js/runtime-main.bff00530.js",
  "static/js/2.8bab6741.chunk.js",
  "static/css/main.262e5e5f.chunk.css",
  "static/js/main.e2f4dbf8.chunk.js"
]
```

In my code I'm doing the following (expanding on [@krylov123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8027397/krylov123)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810590/)):

```php
// get the original values
$manifest = file_get_contents("./asset-manifest.json");
$manifest_values = json_decode($manifest, true);
$entrypoints = $manifest_values['entrypoints'];
```

Then I'm creating two separate arrays: one for the css and another for the js files. In order to do so I've created an helper function `filterPaths` (you may create your own):

```php
// return only paths continaint a specific string
function filterPaths($paths, $value): array {
  return array_filter($paths, function ($filename) use ($value): bool {
    return strpos($filename, $value) !== false;
  });
}
```

Here I create the two arrays:

```php
// filter '.css' files
$css_files = filterPaths($entrypoints, '/css/');
// filter '.js' files
$js_files = filterPaths($entrypoints, '/js/');
```

Then in the html part I loop over the two arrays in order to print `link` tags for CSS and `script` tags for JavaScript.

This is the syntax using blade, but you can adapt it to normal php:

```
@foreach($css_files as $link)
  <link href="{{ $link }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endforeach
```

```
@foreach($js_files as $link)
  <script src="{{ $link }}"></script>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to disable `hash` inserting via `webpack.config.js` file.

You need to find all `[hash]` occurence and remove it from `webpack.config.js`. Then use `npm run` to recompile everything.

For example, you have

```
output: {
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/'),
           filename: '[name].[hash].js'
        }
```

Replace it with:

```
output: {
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/'),
           filename: '[name].js'
        }
```

Comment: This solves the issue but creates a problem if you want to implement cache busting