# Moving the development files for a modify CRA bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, coldfusion, create-react-app

Here are my questions: Where are the development files located for the development build in CRA? How can I move them to another location?

My theory:
If I can locate the files and move them to the correct folders to mimic the same structure as the production files (read more below), I can use the react development tools in FF/Chrome to better trouble shoot bugs.

Here is some background:
I have inherited 2 apps. Both apps are using CFML (Coldfusion/Lucee) on the back end with a modified version of CRA on the front end. When the production files are built by the react build script, an script inside the `package.json` moves the bundle of files to a new folder outside of the app folder structure:

```
../cra-app/build/static/css/main.*.js >> moved to >> ../abc-this-is-my-app/assets/files/main.js
../cra-app/build/static/css/main.*.js.map >> moved to >> ../abc-this-is-my-app/assets/files/main.map
../cra-app/build/static/css/main.*.css >> moved to >> ../abc-this-is-my-app/assets/files/main.css
../cra-app/build/static/css/main.*.css.map >> moved to >> ../abc-this-is-my-app/assets/files/main.css.map
```

Yes this is not normal. This is just how the old developers built this app. This is how the owners of the company want it to stay. Now I have to work around it.

This works fine for production. This does not work for the development build and thus using FF/Chrome React tools is messy.

NOTE: I have search at length. Sorry if this is an easy answer. Also, I am open to other ideas to get these applications running the development build.

Answer (score 0):

Create React app uses webpack dev server that serves files from memory.

Exact config here:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L50

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is to eject from the Create React App setup by running: `npm run eject`.

In this way you'll be able to edit the real configuration, for example I have been able to move the build directory by editing the `config/paths.js` file:

```js
const buildPath = path.join(appDirectory, '../../public/');
module.exports = {
    dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
    appBuild: buildPath,
    // ...
};
```

In order to link the files in development there can be an easier way, but the way that I've done it was by removing all configurations regarding `WebpackDevServer`, creating a custom configuration based on the existing one, and by updating the `package.json` file. The reason I removed WebpackDevServer is because this library creates virtual files which are not easy to link, especially in my case because we are working with PHP files.

I can't copy my exact configuration here, but I can give a little bit more context.

#### Current configuration

In order to see the current configuration you can go to `scripts/start.js` (after ejecting) and add this to log the config variable:

```js
const config = configFactory('development');
console.log(config);
```

#### Create your own

Once you figure out how you want to change it, you can create a new config file (for example `config/webpack.dev.config.js`).

In order to create it you can also re-use the existing `configFactory` function, but you need to modify the original `webpack.config.js` file.

For example, after making enough changes I was able to reduce the `webpack.dev.config.js` file to this:

```
const configFactory = require('./webpack.config');
const config = configFactory('development');
module.exports = config;
```

#### Update `package.json`

Now you can update the `start` script in `package.json`

```
"start_old": "node scripts/start.js",
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config config/webpack.dev.config.js",
```

In order to make this configuration work you'll need two additional packages, so you will have to install them:

```
> npm install cross-env
> npm install webpack-cli
```

#### Linking assets

In order to link the `.css` and `.js` files you will have to look into the `asset-manifest.json` file which is created when building. In this other answer I'm explaining how to do this in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68589475/.

I know it can look complicated, but if you have enough time you'll be able to figure out a solution that best fits your needs.